# Cordova 5.4.0 FileTransfer returns error

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

I'm starting a cordova app (again) and found that the FileTransfer does not bow to my will. This is obviously unacceptable.

To avoid any conflict I have started a new app and installed 3 plugins:

- console
- File
- FileTransfer

I've used the most basic piece of code found on the cordova website with some alterations:

```
var fileTransfer;
var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost:8000/js/test.txt");

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'test.txt',
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false
    );
}
```

Obviously test.txt is reachable. But still the function goes to the error function.

I'm using this function in the browser platform.

I have found a lot of answers on stack, but none of them come close to my version. So I'm wondering if other rulers of code have the same problem or have a tip so I can find and obliterate this error.

My version is 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Well, for all you all-stars out there. There is no immediate problem nor solution. This function only works when running an app. There is no working fallback for browser, even though the console mentions "adding proxy for File". 
Which apparently does not mean what I thought it did.

If I feel like writing a fallback I'll post it here.